# laravel query builder does not allow to do BETWEEN queries like mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I want to check time overlapping using current time with db data. this I done for check shift time overlapping , here example of my database table

```
1 )date:1 shift:1 start_time 04:00 end_time 05:00
2)date:1  shift: 2  start_time 09:00 end_time 11:00
```

particular day has several shifts and when someone edit or add shift a shift for a day  I want to check whther its overlapping

here is my code

```
$shiftData = Shifts::where('time_sheet_id', '=', $timesheet_id->id)
                        ->where('user_id', '=', $driver_id->id)
                        ->where('role_id', '=', 1)
                        ->whereBetween('shift_start_time', array($shift_start , $shift_end))
                        ->whereBetween('shift_end_time' , array($shift_start , $shift_end))
                        ->count();
```

$shift_start and $shift_end are user input values. with this code I'm check if count is 0 time is not overlapping.

so I tried to add time $shift_start :4:20 and $shift_end 4:40, but with this query its return as not overlapping. but it should overlap table currently have time shift to 4 to 5 (start_time 04:00 end_time 05:00)

please advice me how to proceed this query with above scenario

Comment: Can you copy to use your full sql, you can use the method toSql before triggering count();

Comment: @Svetlio : you mean MySQL query which I tried ?

Comment: Yeap just to see what is generated and how do you want it to be..

Comment: What datatype are your `shift_start_time` and `shift_end_time` columns in your database? Are they varchar2?

Comment: What type is `shift_start_time` in your database, and what is the format of `$shift_start`?

Comment: @Svetlio : check my question I updated with MySQL query which I tried

Comment: @Jerodev datatype is "time"

Comment: @MarkBaker datatype is "time"

Comment: Can you show the actual query that is being generated by Eloquent? It will be different to your query, because your Eloquent expression is all ANDs and doesn't have the ORs that your query has..... my suspicion is that's your real problem rather than whereBetween() not working

Comment: @MarkBaker ; please check "UPDATE 2" section in my question

Comment: Update 2 doesn't really answer my question about the query generated by Eloquent; or about why you are using ORs in the straight MySQL query you've shown, but not within your Eloquent expression

Comment: @MarkBaker : do I have to use orWhereBetween instead of whereBetween ? please advice

Comment: I'd probably go for something like: `$shiftData = Shifts::where('time_sheet_id', '=', $timesheet_id->id)
                ->where('user_id', '=', $driver_id->id)
                ->where('role_id', '=', 1)
                ->where(function($q){
                    $q->whereBetween('shift_start_time', [$shift_start , $shift_end]);
                    $q->orWhereBetween('shift_end_time' , [$shift_start , $shift_end]);
                })
                ->count();`

Answer (score 3):

As you've found out, the `whereBetween()` method doesn't support checking if a value is between fields in the database, it only checks if a field in the database is between two values.

Because of this, the simplest option would be just to rewrite your where clauses to manually use the `>=` and `<=` operators.

Try something like:

```
$shiftData = Shifts::where('time_sheet_id', '=', $timesheet_id->id)
    ->where('user_id', '=', $driver_id->id)
    ->where('role_id', '=', 1)
    ->where(function($q1) use ($shift_start, $shift_end) {
        $q1
            ->where(function($q2) use ($shift_start) {
                $q2
                    ->where('shift_start_time', '<=', $shift_start)
                    ->where('shift_end_time', '>=', $shift_start);
            })
            ->orWhere(function($q2) use ($shift_end) {
                $q2
                    ->where('shift_start_time', '<=', $shift_end)
                    ->where('shift_end_time', '>=', $shift_end);
            });
    })
    ->count();
```